# MS Word: Find single italic words

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processing

Is there a way in Microsoft Word to find all single italic words? For example, if the text is:

> This is *some* text.
>
> This is *another line* of text.

Word should find `"some"` but not `"another line"`.

I only managed to find all italic words, but not just single ones. My text is in `.rtf` format. If this is not possible in Word you can also suggest alternatives that work on OS X.

Comment: I couldn't achieve it, but here's a source. Maybe you can take the time to read all of it and see if something there is helpful: http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Comment: @Wally it mentions searching for formatted text in one example (`\1 ((bold))`) but I can't understand how to make it work with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Find window and choose the <kbd>More>></kbd> button.

[image]

Click the <kbd>Format</kbd> button and choose `Font`.

[image]

Choose `Italic` then <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

Now choose find and it will look for words with that formatting.

Comment: Have you tried with my example? It finds all italic words, not just single ones.

Comment: Your question is *"Is there a way in Microsoft Word to find all single italic words?"* That is what I answered, unless you meant something different. Guess I didn't understand what you were asking. Did you mean to ask to find only `non-consecutive` italic words?

Comment: Yes, as it is shown in the example.

Comment: To do that might require VBA. I will look to see if I can find something and update my answer.