# MS Word: How can I dynamically search text and Replace each wrapped result, wrapped with qualifiers?

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processing

First, I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/699843/ms-word-find-single-italic-words) that has helped me solve half my problem where I need to find text that is italicized and of a specific font size.  This works perfectly for finding the text I need to updated.

However, what I'm now wanting to do is run a "Replace" operation, but instead of replacing all instances with a single value, I would like to wrap the text in square brackets.

My reason is because I have a word document that I'd like to do a bit of personal processing on after I convert it to an ASCII format.  These italicized texts are sub-headings and I want to keep them but I need a way to discern what they are.  Wrapping these sub-headings in qualifier text is what I need to do before copying all of the data into ASCII.

How can I do what's basically a relative word search-and-replace, wrapping each instance found with open and close qualifiers?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Ctrl+H
2. Find what:`(<*>)`.
3. Search options: `Use wildcard`
4. Click Format -> Font -> Italic. Press OK.
5. Replace with: `[\1]`
6. Press "Replace All".

[image: Search options]

Comment: This almost works.  It's putting each individual word in square brackets.  Is there a way to do this for each portion of italic text?  [Something like this], rather than [something] [like] [this]?

Comment: @RLH Use `([a-zA-Z ]{1,})` to find consecutive words. However, it won't find individual words.